# How can I disable the newly introduced "download bubble" in Chrome 118?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, download

I use Chrome 118 on Windows 10. I don't want the recently introduced "download bubble": instead, I want to see downloads in the bottom bar where they used to appear.

I disabled `chrome://flags/#download-bubble-v2`:

[image]

It worked for a few versions of Chrome, but it doesn't work on Chrome 118. How can I disable the newly introduced "download bubble" in Chrome 118?

Comment: Vanilla Newest Chrome there is no download bubble just the standard window where to save.  Maybe something in your Chrome profile.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the shortcut to Chrome, open Properties. In the "Target" box, make sure the path to Chrome is contained in double quotes. Put this at the end of the path (making sure there's a space between the last double quote and this line). Working on v120 so guess also v119 and v118 too:

`--disable-features=DownloadBubble`